# Creating a function to calculate slope m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) in R

Tags: r, function, package

I am a new student to programming of any kind and am having trouble creating a function to calculate slope in R.  What do these errors mean that are preventing the function from working?

```
slope <- function(x1,y1,x2,y2) {

missingvars=c(missing(x1),missing(y1),missing(x2),missing(y2))

if(sum(missingvars)>0){
stop(paste(“Values were not provided (denoted by TRUE): x1 -”,missingvars[1],“, y1 -”,missingvars[2],“, x2 -”,missingvars[3],“, 
Y2 -”,missingvars[4],sep=“”))
}

if(x2-x1==0) {
stop(“Both X values are the same, slope cannot be calculated when X are the same.”)
}

m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
return(m)

}
```

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> slope <- function(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
+ 
+ missingvars=c(missing(x1),missing(y1),missing(x2),missing(y2))
+ 
+ if(sum(missingvars)>0){
+ stop(paste(“Values were not provided (denoted by TRUE): x1 -“,missingvars[1],”, y1 -“,missingvars[2],”, x2 -“,missingvars[3],”, 
Error: unexpected input in:
"if(sum(missingvars)>0){
stop(paste(�"
> Y2 -“,missingvars[4],sep=“”))
Error: unexpected input in "Y2 -�"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your text editor is writing the wrong quotation marks. In the code you have the quotation marks “ and ” (look like 66 and 99) but R can only interpret " (looks like ||). If you replace the “ and ” with ", then code doesn't throw any errors for me.

Using a plain text editor like Notepad (Windows), Gedit (Linux) or TextEdit (MacOS) or an IDE like RStudio to write your code should prevent this from happening to you in the future.